# I am getting "expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘/bin’ " in this code. Kindly help

Tags: scripts

```
# !bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
echo "enter a number"                                                                                                   
read a                                                                                                                  
b=0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
while [ "$b" -lt "$a" ]                                                                                                 
do                                                                                                                              
    q=$b                                                                                                                    
    sum=0                                                                                                                    
    while [ "$q" -gt 0 ]                                                                                                    
    do                                                                                                                              
        r=`expr $q % 10`                                                                                                        
        q=`expr $q / 10`                                                                                                        
        sum=`expr $sum + $r /* $r /*$r`                                                                                 
    done                                                                                                                    
    if [ $((sum)) -eq $b ]                                                                                               
    then                                                                                                                            
        echo " $b is armstrong number"                                                                                  
    fi                                                                                                                      
    b=`expr $b + 1`                                                                                                    
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you have

```
# !bin/bash
```

instead of

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: I'd think the actual problem is OP using `/*` instead of the presumably intended `\*`.

Comment: @muru Yep. You are right.